# Inequality with compex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I need to find the roots of a function $f(z)$, given by:

$$ z_{1,2}=\frac{1}{4} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{16}-4 \phi}$$

and the followig condition must hold:

$$-1<z_{1,2}<1$$

Together with the real roots, I must consider also the complex ones that means for $\phi >\frac{1}{64}$

My concern is... the complex roots are still bounded?
Does it make sense the inequality since the complex numbers field is not ordered?

Sorry for the dump question, but I am studying with other people and it looks like I am the only one with this doubt!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An evident generalization would be to look for complex roots $z$ with $|z|<1.$

Comment: I have found that $|z|<1$ holds for $ - \frac{3}{4} < \Phi \le \frac{1}{64} $